# A non-linear system of equations on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I have been looking around and cannot find any solution to this problem. I have 10 variables and 9 (non-linear) equations. I want to solve for every other variable in terms of x (which is one of the 10 variables). Any ideas as to how to do this?

By the way, I am using the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Comment: A google search shows that you can use [fsolve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) to achieve [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/108000-i-have-4-equations-and-3-unknowns-for-trilateration-problem-i-wanna-solve-these-3-unknowns-from-the)

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi I am getting the following error: 
FSOLVE requires all values returned by functions to be of data type
double.

Comment: You can use `solve`, but without providing any example equations/code no-one can help you more than that.